# how to set the property background image of HTML body in skin file in Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, themes, skin

how to set the property background image of HTML body 
in skin file in Asp.Net?

what I need is I need to change the background image of my page like twitter... but by using skin file...

Answer (score 1):

You don't set that property in the **Skin file** but in the **Style File**

in your `style.css` under your `Theme` folder inside `App_Themes` write the property

```
body {
    background: url(images/path.png) repeat 0 0;
}
```

Comment: answer is not clear.. what I need is I need to change the background image of my page like twitter... but by using skin file... vl u plz tell me now... need a help...

Comment: A Skin file is always attached to a style file, just add a new item to your theme and called `style.css`, when you load the new Skin it will load the styles as well ... just verify if you are not been overwritten by any other style. How would you style differently if you have a control in your skin as `<asp:Button CssClass="myBtnClass" />` ? You need to review the use of Themes in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid Skin files are for native Asp.net Controls.

One alternative is to generate your CSS on the fly (or have it already made) and load that CSS for the user in the Code-Behind.  Simply place this in the Head element of your aspx page/masterpage:

```
<link id="Custom_StyleSheet" runat="server"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />
```

And add this to your Master Page (or regular Aspx page):

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        if (boolUseCustomStyleSheet ==  true)
        {
            //This is the relative path of your Css file.
            Custom_StyleSheet.Href  = sColorCssPath;
        }
    }
}
```

If you need more fine grain control, you can make <body> a server-side control like so:

Change <body> to :

```
<body id="someBody" runat="server" >
```

Then add this to your code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    someBody.Style.Add("background-color", "Silver");
}
```

I wouldn't recommend the latter approach, but you could have a list of styles to add based on individual user.  If it's a finite list of styles, then I'd just create the CSS for each of them and then add them dynamically like in the earlier example.